# bash if statement is hit when it is passed zero i.e success

Tags: bash

new_session should be echo'ed as setsid.but it is printing NULL

```
#!/bin/bash
```

x=0

```
if $x;
        then
           new_session="setsid"
        fi

echo $new_session
```

Comment: Try: `_is_linux=false`

Comment: that is exit status of another function couldn't control it

Comment: Do you have a command called `0`?  Your code is testing the exit status of that command; it is not testing whether the value in the variable `$_is_linux` is 0 or any other string.

Comment: you are putting semicolon after if statement. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(( ))` operator evaluates expressions as C arithmetic in `bash`, and has a Boolean return i.e. `(( 0 ))` is false, and `(( 1 ))` is true.

You might need something like below:-

```
#!/bin/bash

_is_linux=0

if ((_is_linux));then
new_session="setsid"
fi
```

(or) more simply

```
#!/bin/bash

_is_linux=0
((_is_linux)) &&  new_session="setsid"
```

Comment: That was a nice one.... i wonder if there is similar syntax for true / false values , in order to built an "if flag then" statement instead of "if flag=true" statement